# Sending Image/File/Audio Files to Browser via websockets/http using mongoose

Tags: c, http, websocket, mongoose-web-server

I am using Mongoose library to have a localhost server run in my system.
Now, through *HTTP Connection* OR *Websocket Connection*, I want to send files/documents/images/small audio files to the client who is making request to the local host.

Until now i was sending a simple json message via websockets and xml data via http connection to client (Browser) by using these Mongoose APIs

```
mg_send_data()
mg_websocket_write()
```

Since Mongoose is being used the whole implementation is in C

Kindly let me know if I can refer to any of the example code if there are any, OR any API documentation of Mongoose which would help me to achieve the above.

Looking forward for valuable responses.

Answer (score 0):

From the github repository you will find :

- [the API documentation](https://github.com/cesanta/mongoose/blob/master/docs/API.md)
- [severals samples](https://github.com/cesanta/mongoose/tree/master/examples) that show how to implement websocket and sending MJPEG